# How to find the number of unconfirmed transactions?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin, confirmations, txpool

Bitcoin has a mempool with [unconfirmed transactions](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions). Where can I find statistics on the size of Ethereum's mempool of unconfirmed transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 23th of June 2017**

Since the ICO craze started which are often badly designed we now have the actual need to see unconfirmed transactions.

With Geth you can use `eth.pendingTransactions` from the console (`geth console` or `geth attach` to an other running Geth instance. This will return all unconfirmed transactions sent from on of the local accounts.

If you want to see all unconfirmed transactions you can use an external service such as [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/txsPending).

**Original answer**

I don't think this feature is implemented in any of the clients yet.

With a blocktime of 15 seconds the amount of unconfirmed transactions, at this stage in the network, is just never large enough to warrant showing these statistics.

If you take a look at the [Ethereum Network Status page](https://stats.ethdev.com/) you can see that each block holds about 2 or 3 transactions meaning that is probably the amount that was unconfirmed at one point.

Comment: What's the difference with Geth's `eth.pendingTransactions` ?

Comment: I believe `eth.pendingTransactions` only shows local transactions that you created.

Comment: Got it: it only shows what your node has created, no pending transactions from other nodes.

Comment: We may be having a need for this now: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/577iv5/cannot_send_any_transaction_tried_myetherwallet/

Comment: This answer was flagged by a user as out of date. Updated answers from the community would be welcome.